# Unable to find images when running selenium/sikuli scripts using Ant

Tags: ant, selenium, testng, sikuli

I've written a couple selenium scripts (Java) and use sikuli to verify the images exist. It worked fine when I ran the tests through Eclipse/TestNG but with Ant I'm getting the following error:

[testng] [error] resources/x.png looks like a file, but can't be found on the disk. Assume it's text.

The following is my build.xml, please let me know if there's more information I can provide.

```
<project name="test" default="test">
    <property name="src.dir" location="src" />
<property name="build.dir" location="build" />
<property name="dist.dir" location="dist" />
<property name="lib.dir" location="lib" />

    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

    <target name="makedir" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
</target>

    <!-- Compiles the java code -->
<target name="compile" depends="clean, makedir">
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" classpathref="build.classpath"/>      
</target>

<!--Creates the deployable jar file  -->
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}\build.test.ant.jar" basedir="${build.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="test.Main" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

    <taskdef resource="testngtasks" classpath="${lib.dir}/testng-6.5.2.jar"/>

    <target name="test" depends="jar">
      <testng 
   classpath="${build.dir}:${lib.dir}/selenium-java-2.24.1.jar:${lib.dir}/selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar:${lib.dir}/sikuli-script.jar"
   outputDir="${testng.report.dir}"
   testname="test1">
       <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng.xml" />
      </testng>
      <fail message="BUILD FAILURE" if="failed" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: where is your image directory for the test to pull the images from? From what I can see, this is the same error I received when I would not pull the correct directory that was holding my image resource.

Comment: I put it under project/resources/x.jpg

Comment: Where are you defining the path to these images though? Do you have a test.config file or a BaseSeleniumTest.java file that you do all of your setup in?

Comment: I vaguely remember what I did to fix it but I remember asking this question on the sikuli forum: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/210866